# DAO.Recordset.Update results in reckord lock

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba

I am trying to run the following code to loop around a recordset and do updates where neccessary.

I have a Microsoft Access database connected to a MySql backend. Whenever I run this code I get the following error:

> 3197 error: The Microsoft Office Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.

The code is below:

```
Private Sub test()
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, rsCnt As Long, i As Long

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryMyQuery", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)
    rs.MoveLast
    rsCnt = rs.RecordCount
    rs.MoveFirst
    For i = 1 To rsCnt
        rs.Edit
        rs!MyFieldInTable = "test"
        rs.Update
    Next i
End Sub
```

I thought the Access database might be corrupt so I pulled an earlier backup but it's doing the same thing which makes me think it's a MySql issue.

We use an identical piece of code on another version of this database linked to a different MySql table and it works fine.

Also, when I open the query the record-set is based on I can edit the data in the query without any issues.

Just to add, on the first loop, rs!MyFieldInTable is updated, then I get the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not appear that you are moving to another record in the recordset. Simply incrementing `i` doesn't move to the next record. A more traditional approach would be to iterate over the recordset without the need for your other variables (`i` and `rsCnt`).

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("qryMyQuery", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)
rs.moveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!FieldNameHere = "test"
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

**EDIT**
After a bit of searching I came across [this thread](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MySQL/Q_22520389.html) which seems to be similar to your issue. At the bottom of the thread a suggestion is made to modify the ODBC settings for your MySQL DSN by selecting the "Advanced" tab and selecting the option to "Return Matching Rows". The post also says to drop the linked table and then re-link it to your Access database.
I haven't used Access with MySQL in the past, so I have no idea whether this will work or not, so proceed with caution!

You may also try changing your recordset to use the dbOptimistic flag for the recordset locking option to see if that helps at all:

`set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordSet("qryMyQuery", DB_OPEN_DYNASET, dbOptimistic)`

Comment: +1 Like @XIVSolutions, I was writing a similar answer when I got the message that a new answer had been loaded.

Comment: Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe the rs.Edit has to go inside the loop.  From the DAO help file: **Edit Method:** *Copies the **current record** from an updatable Recordset object to the copy buffer for subsequent editing.*

Comment: @mwolfe02: Thanks, I think you are correct. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys I really appreciate it but I am still getting the same issue (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/15/imageshackgu.jpg/). I'm a bit stumped.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, in the end I just re-wrote the code to do 'DoCmd.RunSQL' queries for the updates instead of updating the recordset. I've taken all of your advice on board though. =)

Comment: It's better to use the .Execute method of a DAO.Database object variable and include dbFailOnError as @mwolfe02 described.  Also add an error handler to deal with anything dbFailOnError surfaces.  One consequence of DoCmd.RunSQL is that folks often turn SetWarnings off to avoid the confirmation messages.  With SetWarnings off you risk suppressing important information which will then hamper troubleshooting efforts.

Comment: I want to re-iterate what @HansUp just said.  You will save yourself lots of heartache someday if you get in the habit of using .Execute with dbFailOnError instead of the Warnings False/RunSQL/Warnings True approach.  I know of no good reason to use DoCmd.RunSQL.

Comment: This code example has a few minor problems. 1) DB_OPEN_DYNASET should be changed to dbOpenDynaset 2) I recommend adding a check to see if the recordset contains records. 3) I recommend closing the recordset object and setting it to nothing at the end.

Comment: @Hk1: I agree, though the intent of this sample wasn't to showcase the full text that one would normally write in production quality code, it was simply to illustrate how to iterate over the recordset without using integers as the poster originally had illustrated with the sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Two things you can try.  First, try adding the dbSeeChanges option when opening the recordset:

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database
Set db = Currentdb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryMyQuery", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)
Do Until rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!FieldNameHere = "test"
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The other option, as @HansUp suggested, is to use a SQL update statement instead of a dynamic recordset.  The key there is to open the recordset as a snapshot, so that changes you make to the records do not affect the recordset itself.

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset, db As DAO.Database
Set db = Currentdb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryBatchPayments", dbOpenSnapshot)
Do Until rs.EOF
    db.Execute "UPDATE Payments " & _
               "SET DCReference='test' " & _
               "WHERE PaymentID=" & !PaymentID, dbFailOnError
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and my solution turned out to be the default value for BIT(1) fields. Access does not like these to be null. Make sure you use either 0 or 1 in mysql for these fields.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have MySQL here to try this against, but it looks to me as if your code is not advancing the recordset after the rs.Update method is executed, so that you are trying to udate the same field in the fierst record.

Add this line after the rs.Update:

```
rs.MoveNext
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Also, the code posted by Tim Lentine is a more elegant way to do it. He posted while I was still writing my answer.

Comment: If people are going to downvote, it would be just peachy if they would accompany the down vote with some reasoning. Just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

Try calling OpenRecordset from an object variable set to CurrentDb(), rather than directly from CurrentDb().

```
Dim rs as DAO.Recordset
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = Currentdb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("qryMyQuery", DB_OPEN_DYNASET)
rs.moveFirst
Do Until rs.EOF
    rs.Edit
    rs!FieldNameHere = "test"
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

The reason for that suggestion is I've found operations on CurrentDb directly can throw an error about "block not set".  But I don't get the error when using an object variable instead.  And ISTR OpenRecordset was one such operation where this was an issue.

Also, my impression was your approach is a cumbersome way to accomplish the equivalent of:

```
UPDATE qryMyQuery SET FieldNameHere = "test";
```

However, I suspect the example is a proxy for a real world situation where the recordset approach is useful.  Still that makes me wonder whether you would see the same or a different error when executing the UPDATE statement.

If you continue to have trouble with this, it may help to show us the SQL View for qryMyQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that if one tries to save data which are the same as the one already in the MySql record Access will display this kind of error. I've tried some suggestions from this thread but did not help.

The simple solution for this is to save a slightly diffrent data by using a manual time-stamp. Here is an example of heaving a sort order field and setting it to 10, 20, 30...

```
    i = 10
    timeStamp = Now()
    Do Until Employee.EOF
        Employee.Edit
        Employee!SortOrderDefault = i
        Employee!LastUpdated = timeStamp
        Employee.Update
        i = i + 10
        Employee.MoveNext
    Loop
```

I've tried automatic time-stamp in the MySql table but did not help when the new entry data is the same as the old one.

Comment: I experienced the same. Mentioned in this MySQL bug report: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=46406
It seems to be caused by the way Access forms its update queries. It can be solved like you suggest client-side, or server-side using a `timestamp` column.

Answer (score 0):

My little helpful hint is, bits are very, very, very bad data types to use when linking SQL tables to Microsoft Access because only SQL Server understands what a bit is, Microsoft Access has a hard time interpreting what a bit is. Change any bit datatypes to int (integers) and relink your tables that should clear things up. Also, make sure your Booleans always contain a 1 or a 0 (not a yes/no or a true/flase) in your VBA code or your updates will fail to the linked SQL tables because Microsoft Access will try to update them with a True/False or a Yes/No and SQL will not like that.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem; i solved them adding those to code using dao.recordset:

```
**rst.lockedits = true**
rst.edit
rst.fields(...).value = 1 / rst!... = 1
rst.update
**rst.lockedits = false**
```

this seems fix conflict between just opened data (such as in a form) and updating them with code.

Sorry for my bad english... i read a lot but i never had learn it! I'm just italian.

Comment: Attention if you have changed your code to SQL statement. The Form_Unload event try to update the same data you have changed by the SQL and raises a not  manageable error; this can vanify all your app.