# MySQL & MsAccess 2007 - Error 3197 When Trying to Update

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm migrating an Access Database to MySQL.
Most of the program works well but I still have a problem with an SQL query.

I obtain a 3197 Run Time Error :

```
The Microsoft Office Access database engine stopped the process because you and another user are attempting to change the same data at the same time.
```

What I have already done :

- Configure my ODBC Driver to allow Dynamic Cursors
- Configure my ODBC Driver to return matched rows instead of affected rows

The code which causes the error :

```
Dim rsMain As Recordset
Dim rs As Recordset

Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb

Dim sqlQuery As String

sqlQuery = "Select * from Table1 where field1 like '" & Me.field10 & "*' and field2=" & Me.field11 & " and field3=True"
Set rsMain = db.OpenRecordset(sqlQuery)

rsMain.MoveFirst
Do Until rsMain.EOF
    sqlQuery = "select sum(field4) as Est, sum(field5) as Cons, sum(field6) as Prod from Table1 where field1 like '" & rsMain("field1") & "*' and field3=False and field5=" & Me.modifiedDate
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlQuery)

    rsMain.Edit
    rsMain.Fields("field4") = rs.Fields("Est")
    Set rs = Nothing

    rsMain.Update
    rsMain.MoveNext
Loop
Set rsMain = Nothing
```

The rsMain.Update command fails, it's where the error come from.
I have similar code which don't cause any error. I am the only user at the time.

Thanks in advance for your insights

Comment: Thanks, it was typo error. It's what I have in my code. requeteSQL is sqlQuery in french

Comment: I have simplified and changed the name of the variables, but i forgot to change a few.

Comment: the dtAvancement is the result of a function which changes the date format.

Comment: @Galephico When working with a db server back-end and an Access front-end, you are best to avoid using linked tables and the currentdb reference. Access reads the tables in it's native DAO format, you are much better to open up ADO connections to your MYSQL database as then queries are executed server side rather than client side. This doesn't strictly answer the question but is something to bear in mind when moving your back-end data out of Access.

Comment: @Galephico As for the question, I think you may need to move the "set rs = nothing" to after the "rsmain.update" and also consider adding "dbopendynaset" on your Open Recordset's

Comment: @MattDonnan Thanks. I have already moved the "set rs = nothing" to after the "rsmain.update" and added "dbopendynaset" but it hasn't solved my problem. I'm trying to use the ADO connections but have difficulties to get data from the linked table - CurrentProject.Connection doesn't seem to get the datas. Any ideas why ?

Comment: @Galephico Are you using "CurrentProject.Connection" for local MS Access tables, or for the linked MYSQL tables?

Comment: @MattDonnan for the linked MySQL tables. I have migrated all my MS Access tables to linked tables. I'm searching on the web a simple way to connect through my DSN

Comment: @Galephico Sorry, I didn't make it clear, you don't have linked tables with ADO, you just open recordsets and work with those, you can find the MySQL connection strings on http://www.connectionstrings.com You will want one of the ODBC options : )

Comment: Check my answer on this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965455/access-vba-run-time-error-3197/10685946#10685946

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the `rsMain.Edit/Update` I used directly the SQL update using `DoCmd.RunSQL SQLQuery` where SQLQuery is my updated SQL query.