# Access -- Form fields permanently broken after Recordset.close

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I have a form with several text and combo boxes bound to records of a table, which we'll call "Foo".

"Foo" is a filtered down copy of a larger table "Bar". This was done to allow reversible edits to Foo, which would be merged back into Bar when the user was finished editing

My implementation of reverting a specific record back to Bar's copy worked but caused [Run-time error '3197'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965455/access-vba-run-time-error-3197) when form's recordset was modified any time after.

To workaround this I thought of closing my form's recordset, running my query, then reopening it, so that there wouldn't be any fights over usage. I put `Me.recordset.close` before running the revert query, but this caused the bound fields in my form to permanently break:

[image]

This persists even when closing the form, and even when closing Access. The listbox in the form which shows the table data works fine, as does the primaryID field and the query, so I don't understand what the problem is. This event is triggered by a button press, so why would the recordset not be restored when the form is reloaded?

How can I fix this without reverting to an earlier version of the Access file?

Comment: You are making it _way_ too complicated. Browse for a tutorial: "Beginning with Microsoft Access" or similar and look up the very basics: Filtering a bound form.

Comment: Start by decompiling the database: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ms-access/8207/how-to-troubleshoot-access-crashes/26371/decompile-database#t=20170712201408237706

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem but does not provide me with any insight.

Under `Form Design Tools > Design > Tools > Add Existing Fields` I dragged and dropped a second copy of each of the problem fields onto the form then immediately deleted it. When the form was reloaded, everything worked properly.